# Game server with ZMQ sockets

Tags: zeromq

I tried to write a game server with ZMQ sockets. The server is using a ZMQ_REP socket and the client a ZMQ_REQ socket.

This works only if one client is connected. If I connect a second client then communication breaks between the server and the first client.

Which server <-> client pattern works for one server and multiple clients?

Comment: For a game you probably want both request-reply, and publish-subscribe. You'd use long-running pub-sub sessions for the server to push global state updates to the clients, and you'd use short-lived req-rep for the clients to transmit player actions and get some immediate answer. (Disclaimer: I've never actually written a multiplayer game, this is more of a gut feeling based on the 0MQ docs.)

Comment: Also going by the docs, I don't see how this would happen: "If I connect a second client then communication breaks between the server and the first client." They strongly imply that incoming requests on a `ZMQ_REP` socket are queued and that the server will eventually get to all of them assuming it's not overloaded. You might want to show some code on what you're actually doing and where you find out a first client is disconnected.

Comment: @millimoose Use async REQ/REP, synchronous is too brittle for real-world application due to its blocking nature.

Comment: @raffian You can overcome the blocking nature by using a different thread dedicated to REQ/REP. You could also poll multiple sockets as described in the 0MQ guide.

Answer (score 1):

for servers, you want to use ROUTER, and for clients, DEALER. There are a lot of examples of this in the ZeroMQ Guide. It's worth reading through that (or buy the book) and learning the different patterns, as you try simple models of your own. Don't try to build anything too complex to start with.

Comment: I now used two threads and for each client a different socket. There are only two players and this works with the REQ & REP combination. It's not the best solution but it works.